# Reveal in PathFinder/Finder

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, pathfinder

We are using AppleScript to reveal files from our application in the Finder.
If a user has alternatives, e.g., PathFinder, installed as a replacement for Finder, how we can find our what application to tell the AppleScript commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this:

```
try
    tell application "Path Finder" to reveal "/Users/danielbeck/Downloads"
on error
    tell application "Finder" to reveal folder "Downloads" of home
end try
```

But this assumes that a user with Path Finder prefers it for the reveal functionality.

---

Alternatively,

`do shell script "open 'file:///Users/danielbeck/Downloads'"`

When a user has configured Path Finder to handle `file://` URLs, this will open the folder in Path Finder. Only works with folders though.

---

You can use the following to get a list of processes:

```
tell application "System Events"
    processes
end tell
```

Look for a process named Finder. If not found, the user has no running Finder. Or look for one named Path Finder, and if found, use it instead. Etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, configuring Path Finder to handle *Reveal* actions from other applications doesn't extend to AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

While @Daniel Beck has provided a good answer above, here is a handler I use to reveal in Finder the item currently selected in Path Finder.  Often I need to do something in the Finder window, so I have added a pause until the Finder window name is the same as the Path Finder window name.

For future reference, I'm maintaining this snippet in my GistHub at:
[revealPFItemInFinder.applescript](https://gist.github.com/JMichaelTX/6b2389ec8ffdba12beb6680c32ed7668#file-revealpfiteminfinder-applescript)

````
```applescript
--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
on revealPFItemInFinder()
  --–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
  (*  VER: 2.0    2018-03-15
    PURPOSE:  Reveal Item in Finder that is Selected in Path Finder

    RETURNS:  alias of item selected in both Finder and Path Finder

    AUTHOR:  JMichaelTX
  --–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
  *)

  --- GET THE ITEM SELECTED IN PATH FINDER ---

  tell application "Path Finder"
    set fileList to (get selection)
    if ((fileList is missing value) or ((count of fileList) ≠ 1)) then error ("You must select only ONE file in Path Finder.")
    set pfWinName to name of window 1
    set itemPath to POSIX path of item 1 of fileList
  end tell

  set itemAlias to alias POSIX file itemPath

  --- REVEAL SAME ITEM IN FINDER ---

  tell application "Finder"
    activate -- to make sure reveal will be in frontmost window
    reveal itemAlias

    --- Now Wait for New Finder Window with Same Name as Path Finder ---

    set finWinName to name of window 1

    set maxWaitTime to 2.0
    set delayTime to 0.1
    set waitTime to 0

    repeat while finWinName ≠ pfWinName
      delay delayTime
      set finWinName to name of window 1
      set waitTime to waitTime + delayTime
      if (waitTime > maxWaitTime) then error "Max wait time of " & maxWaitTime & " exceeded waiting for Finder Window of " & pfWinName
    end repeat

  end tell

  return itemAlias

end revealPFItemInFinder

```
````